# I want to make a new column that sets values from a previous column to a different value in R

Tags: r

for example if a value in col 2 is "MED" then in a new col3, it should be assigned 1.
if a value in col 2 is "PAT", then in col3, it appears as 2.

Comment: `ifelse` will help you

Comment: Or build a lookup table and merge

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is with the `mutate` and `case_when` functions from the `dplyr` function:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(col3 = case_when(
               col2 == 'MED' ~ 1,
               col2 == 'PAT' ~ 2))
```

This creates a new column in `df` called `col3` whose value is `1` when the value of `col2` for that row  `== 'MED'` and `2` when `col2 == 'PAT'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse()` is a fast way to accomplish this:

```
df <- data.frame('col_2' = c('MED', 'MED', 'PAT', 'PAT'))

df$col_3 <- c()

df$col_3 <- ifelse(df$col_2 == 'MED', 1, 2)
```